# A song in only 100x18 pixels

Tags: visual, music

Below is a very small image (only 100x18 pixels) which represents a song. What song am I looking for?

[image: song]

Comment: rot13(Zvffrq bccbeghavgl sbe gurer gb or jbeqcynl vaibyivat "YnFfb").

Comment: Is it sad that I still know all the words?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is [Do Re Mi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-Re-Mi) from the film "The Sound of music
>  
>  The first picture is a deer,
>  
>  The second a ray
>  
>  The third is 2 arrows pointing at a person, thus "Mi"
>  
>  Two locations represents Far
>  
>  The fifth is a needle, representing So
>  
>  Sixth is a note, representing La
>  
>  The last is a cup, representing Tea

Comment: Well done, and very fast! Don't forget the long arrow below all icons ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the song

> Do-Re-Mi from The Sound of Music.

The icons in the image represent the items to which

> the notes in the sol-fa scale are compared.

Answer (score -1):

The first image is

> a Doe. A deer. A female deer.

The second is

> a Ray. A drop of golden sun.

Next is

> Me. A name a I call myself.

Then

> we go Far, a long, long way to run.

After that is

> Sew, a needle pulling thread.

Then comes

> La, a note to follow Sew.

Finally,

> some Tea, a drink with jam and bread.

And the arrow

> brings us back to Doe. Oh oh!

I told you I knew all the words